# What web applications are available for allowing users to download software?

Tags: web-apps, download-manager

Pretty much as the title says, I'm looking for an application that can function as a sort of download centre for bits of software from a variety of different authors. None of the software is paid, I'm not looking for an e-commerce solution, more along the lines of what Curse has for Minecraft mods (http://www.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft) where it's basically just a list of mods and you can see more mods by the author, in the same category etc.

I'd like to look at a couple of options and if you could provide some pros and cons that would be great. I'd rather it be written in something that doesn't require installation (like PHP and MySQL, where it's just run on most common webservers) not a Linux package or something similar. Open-source is preferred, but so long as it's free I can live with it being closed.

(Moved from Web Applications)

Comment: Any specific browser or o/s?

Comment: @Mawg I want something on the server-side, not client. Like a download centre.